# Is there a way to detect whether or not the user has a mousewheel, perhaps with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I know that some mice/mouses have scroll wheels and some do not.  Additionally, mobile devices don't really have a mousewheel event.  I would like to be able to detect when the mousewheel is not available in order to allow for alternative editing methods.  In my case, this will be rare, but I still want to handle it.

I'm using jQuery 3.1.1.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why does it matter if the user has a mousewheel or not?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In this case, the UI would be much simpler if the user were able to employ the mousewheel.

Comment: Having a mousewheel and the user being able to use one are not the same thing.  They could have motor disability or some other issue that stops them being able to use the wheel.  Maybe it's broken or so dirty it doesn't work any more.   *If* it could report it existed, it would still do so in these cases.   Please rethink your UX.

Comment: @freedomn-m You make a good point.  In this case, there are a limited number of users.

Comment: Ok - so assuming it's an in-house app, make the minimum requirements of using your app to be a mouse with a wheel.  Or add a "click here if you don't have a mousewheel" at the top.

Comment: @freedomn-m Good thought.  So... no?  There is no way to detect a mousewheel?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and would not expect there to be given my comment above.  However, that does not rule out the possibility; someone  may know otherwise.

Comment: If there was, it would probably be in [modernizr](https://modernizr.com) or [feature.js](http://featurejs.com/).

Comment: @freedomn-m Ok.  Thanks.